# How to get a single key (random ok) from a very large hash in perl?

Tags: perl, hash

Suppose you have a very large hash (lots of keys), and have a function that potentially deletes many of those keys, e.g.:

```
while ( each %in ) {
  push @out, $_;
  functionThatDeletesOneOrMoreKeys($_, \%in);
}
```

I believe `each` in this case is an efficient way to pull a single key from the hash, but the documentation says `each` should not be used when deleting keys from the hash.

Otherwise I could use `while (%in) { $_ = (keys(%in))[0] ....` but that seems horribly inefficient for a very large hash.

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Why is the function inside the loop to begin with, if it doesn't depend on $_? At best, the loop/function should just capture all keys that need deleted, then delete them outside the first loop.

Comment: Good point, it does.  I edited the question.  Of course my real problem is quite a bit more complex...

Comment: This sounds like an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) - Would you be able to clarify further the scenario here? I would be thinking _probably_ `grep`/`map` to execute a transform, but it rather depends on quite what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: Yes, I know -- the real problem is quite complex, i.e. I'm trying to take a list, e.g. a file list, and generate a shell wildcard string to represent that list.  For example, if I input "myfile_1,a", "myfile_1,cat", "myfile_2,a", and "myfile_2,cat", I'd like my script to return "myfile_[12],{a,cat}".  This should work for arbitrarily complex list items.  Each list item is a hash key, and my subroutine seeks for contiguous rectangular blocks in multi-dimensions, deleting them from the hash as it goes.  The outer loop continues as long as the hash is not empty and starts with a random element.

Comment: See why I tried to simplify?  ;)

Comment: I see, but I think that would be a useful thing to have included, because it helps understand the problem. And you might have seen alternative suggestions for solving it. This feels like a kind of thing that prior art exists.

Comment: Agreed, it feels like that, but my Google-fu isn't strong enough to find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be a horrible thing to do, and it would be better if you explained what you were trying to achieve

However the problem with deleting hash elements while iterating using `each` is that `each` holds a state value for the hash that depends on the hash remaining unchanged

You can clear that state by calling `keys` (or `values`) on the same hash.

Here's an example which deletes the three elements with the given key and those before and after it in an attempt to emulate what your `function_that_deletes_one_or_more_keys` (which is what it should be called) might do

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';
use feature 'say';

my %h = map +( $_ => 1), 0 .. 9;

while ( my $key = each %h ) {

    say $key;

    delete @h{$key-1, $key, $key+1};

    keys %h;     # Reset "each" state
}
```

I recommend that you don't use the global `$_` variable for this

### output

```
2
9
4
6
0
```

Comment: If you're deleting the current element, you don't need to reset the iterator as that is explicitly safe. If you're deleting other keys, this solution would very likely result in an infinite loop.

Comment: @ikegami: Yes, we have to assume that the OP's subroutine deletes the element with the current key as well as any others, otherwise it will result in an endless loop.

Comment: @ikegami: Although I can't get `each` in my program above, which deletes three elements at once, to return *false* before the hash is empty even without the call to `keys`. It seems perfectly well behaved

Comment: 1) Deleting other keys may behave as desired, but the documentation explicitly forbids it. It may not always work, or it may stop working. 2) But that's not what I was talking about. I meant if you ever go through a pass without deleting the current key (which sounds possible for the OP), this solution would result in an infinite loop

Comment: @ikegami: All of that is perfectly clear. Take a look at what my comments say

Answer (score 0):

General advice without knowing details of the complexity to which you refer:

**Change** the function lines that delete keys to instead store the keys to be deleted in an array or hash (or file). After the first loop completes, loop through **that** array or hash (or file) and delete those keys from the first hash.

Answer (score 0):

```
my @in_keys = keys %in;
for (@in_keys)  {
    if (exists $in{$_}) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Or do as Borodin shows, resetting the iterator each time you know you've deleted at least one element.